# Why does this unit test fail when comparing two doubles?

Tags: c#, vb.net, nunit

I have the following code in vb.net that calculates the amount before tax was applied:

```
Public Shared Function CalculateRateBeforeTax(ByVal rate As Decimal, ByVal tax As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim base As Decimal = rate / (1 + (tax / 100.0))
    Return Math.Round(base,2)
End Function
```

Some scenarios I setup were:

Rate = 107, Tax = 7%, Base = 100

Rate = 325, Tax = 6.5%, Base = 305.16

Rate = 215, Tax = 125%, Base = 95.55

I put the above scenarios into some unit tests using c# and using the nunit testing framework.  The first scenario passes, but the other fails and I am not sure how I can get it to pass.  Here is are my tests:

```
[TestFixture]
class TaxTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CalculateRateBeforeTax_ShouldReturn100_WhenRateIs107AndTaxIs7Percent()
    {
        decimal expected = 100.0m;
        decimal actual = TaxUtil.CalculateRateBeforeTax(107.0m, 7.0m);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CalculateRateBeforeTax_ShouldReturn305point16_WhenRateIs325AndTaxIs6point5Percent()
    {
        decimal expected = 305.16m;
        decimal actual = TaxUtil.CalculateRateBeforeTax(325.0m, 6.5m);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CalculateRateBeforeTax_ShouldReturn95point55_WhenRateIs215AndTaxIs125Percent()
    {
        decimal expected = 95.55m;
        decimal actual = TaxUtil.CalculateRateBeforeTax(215.0m, 125.0m);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

As I said before, the first test passes, but the results of the other tests are:

Second Test expected 305.1600000000000003d But was: 305.1643192488263d

Third Test expected 95.54999999999997 But was: 95.55555555555555557d

Comment: For monetary you should really be using decimal

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103163)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take out a calculator and enter the following: 325 / (1 + (6.5 / 100.0))

The result is 305.164319...

Then you're asking if 305.164319... is equal to 305.16. The test obviously fails, they are not the same numbers.

Now if you're wondering why you have slightly different numbers than this, like 305.1600000000000003 instead of 305.16, this is because there is some loss of precision with Double type. You can use the Decimal type for more precision.

But the most important problem is that the value returned by CalculateRateBeforeTax is not truncated correctly to have precision up to the cent. You just have to truncate two decimals like this:

```
Dim rounded As Decimal = Math.Floor(base * 100) / 100
```

Now by changing Double type by Decimal type your Assert should work.

Comment: There is a overload of round taking the desired number of fractional digits. So you can throw out *100/100 stuff.

Comment: Thanks I just did the change.

Comment: Why does Math.Round(base,2) not round 305.l64319 to 305.16?

Comment: I have done what you said above, changed everything to decimal and did Math.Round(base,2) in the vb.net code and it still brings back the whole number.  It wasn't until I brought the calculation into the unit test that it passed.

Comment: Might be some subtleness of VB. I don't know VB.

Comment: Maybe you just didn't rebuild the VB project before running your tests? I just tested it to make sure and Math.Round(base, 2) works perfectly in VB.

Comment: Ok, I did a rebuild and actually removed the logic from the unit test and 2 of the 3 tests passed.  The third test is expected 95.55, but the value returned was 95.56.

Comment: For the 3rd scenario, 215/(1 + 2.25) = 95.55555555 and when I do a Math.Round(95.5555555,2), it returns 95.56. I wonder how I can prevent it from rounding the second decimal up to 6.

Comment: ...but the rounded result IS 95.56. If you actually want to remove decimals instead of rounding, use Math.Floor(value * 100) / 100

Comment: Math.Floor(base) returns 95, but I want 95.55

Comment: I did Math.Floor(base * 100) / 100, but this returns 95

Comment: I assure you that Math.Floor(95.5555555D * 100) / 100 = 95.55

Comment: @Xaisoft your problem is that you didn't look up how to correctly round taxes. You can only implement it correctly if you know the law specifying the rounding.

Comment: I did Math.Floor(base * 100) / 100, but it returns 95m

Comment: Step through your code, that's impossible with 95.5555.. as input.

Comment: ok, sorry for the confusion, I did not know I actually had to build the unit test project as well. After that, Math.Floor and Math.Truncate worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations. Your Unit Tests have actually done what they are supposed to do and found a bug with the code you are testing.

You have rounding errors. Unfortunately this is being caused by the VB.NET code you are trying to Unit Test rather than the code in your actual tests.

You need to use a data type with more precision. I would suggest replacing your use of `Double` with `Decimal`.

Comment: I strongly doubt that his mistake was caused by the limited precision of double. Of course he should use `Decimal`, but I don't think this fixes his problem.

Comment: I changed to decimal, but the second and third test still fail.  I am even trying to do Math.Round(305.16432,2) to get 305.16, but it is still returning the whole number.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - What makes you think it would be caused by another issue? The OP (and the code they are Unit Testing) performs quite a few calculations using doubles and the results that are posted definitely look like rounding errors caused by loss of precision to me.

Comment: @Xaisoft - Did you change the data types in your tests or the data types in the VB.NET code (both locals and the input types)?

Comment: Because double rounding errors would be observed in much less significant digits.

Comment: I changed the datatypes everywhere, in the vb.net code and in the unit tests.  I got it to work, but I actually had to change my unit test expected to decimal expected = Math.Round(325.0m / (1 + (6.5m/100.0m)),2); Once I did this, it worked.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Not necessarily. It depends on how many operations were done (each operation compounds the error).

Comment: The method is is in a vb.net project, but the unit tests are just in a c# console app.

Comment: But in this case the operations are of such a kind that the error won't be visible in such significant digits. I'm 99% sure that these large errors with this code aren't caused by double precision problems.

Comment: @Xaisoft - Mis-understood your previous comment...deleted mine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee that floating point numbers are the same as each other, even when they appear so.

It depends on a number of factors such as processor, architecture, etc.  As Justin has said, use decimal if precision is required.

Have a look at Jon Skeets excellent blog post:  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: While that's true, I don't think that this does explain the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

While the other posters are right stating that you should use `Decimal` instead of `Double` that isn't the cause of your observed problem.

The observed problem is caused by logical mistakes in your rounding code. You need to look up how to correctly round such values. This is a question of laws, and not math.

Another strange thing is that your `CalculateRateBeforeTax` rounds its return value to an integral value, but the values you posted seem to be calculated without that rounding.

Comment: Yes that is confusing, Math.Round(x, 2) is supposed to round the number to 2 decimal places, but it is returning the whole number as if it is not rounding.

Comment: Even once you fix that problem your code might be incorrect. You need to look it up in the specification, i.e. your tax laws.

Comment: And when I test very similar code in LinqPad it works as expected